# Shorting down many if clauses

Tags: python, if-statement

I've got this little thing in my code but 5 times as long... Is it possible to short it down in any way?

```
if counter==1:
    x1=x+0.1
    x-=0.1
    x_add=0.01
if counter==2:
    x1=x+0.01
    x-=0.01
    x_add=0.001
if counter==3:
    x1=x+0.001
    x-=0.001
    x_add=0.0001
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using another variable?

```
factor = 1.0 / (10 ** counter) # x=1 -> 0.1 ; x=2 ->0.01 ...
x1 = x + factor
x -= factor
x_add = factor / 10
```

I did not test this, but the idea is clear. No `if`s needed.

Comment: Thanks thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Looks like exponent of 0.1 follows the `counter` like this:

```
x1 = x + 0.1 ** counter
x -= 0.1 ** counter
x_add = 0.1 ** (counter + 1)
```